# How to load public route into Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, offline

Let's say there is a route:

https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=pl&msa=0&msid=104314102588659350539.00043799567b09d5f132f&z=12

I have Google Maps (application) in my Android phone.

**QUESTION**: how can I load a route (as one above) so I could later turn it on (to see it over the map) and off (not to delete, just to make it disappear from the map)?

*I am interested in downloading it (storing) for later off-line usage.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the route you want to take offline in Google Maps app:
[image: Google Maps Android App showing public route]

How did I take it to Google Maps app? Well, I opened this question in [Dolphin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) and tapped the [link you provided](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=pl&msa=0&msid=104314102588659350539.00043799567b09d5f132f&z=12). It gave me `Share via..` pop-up from which I chose `Maps`. Done!

To push links to Android device, you don't need to publish it on web. There are plenty of options available viz. AirDroid. You can use Gmail too. In Android device, just open that link in web browser.

If `Share via..` pop-up doesn't appear with your web browser, it means that its not tightly integrated with Android. I'd recommend you to use Dolphin Browser because I have tested it.

To make it offline, just hit `Options` key & you'll find `Make available offline` option...
[image: Make available offline option of Google Maps]

To later use this map, just tap `Layers` icon on top bar (on bottom bar in ICS) & choose the route:
[image: Layers icon of Google Maps app]

**Note:** I've put screenshots from a Gingerbread device. My ICS device is currently not available. If you're running ICS or above, it'll be slightly different.

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately I have ICS, and here when I select "make available offline" in Google Maps (application) GM stores the map (of the region) not the route. So when I get back to the data I stored, all I have is pure map, without any route. Any idea how to make a difference for GM between route and map (region)?

Comment: @macias When you are connected with internet, tap `Layers` icon & choose the route you opened from Dolphin. After that, you can go offline & send Google Maps in background.

Comment: Google hasn't implemented pure offline navigation yet. You can just pre-cache map, currently. But, with my trick, you can enjoy navigation offline.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you for clarification. I hope they will add this feature, because this "cache" (it is not a cache really, because if you switch to pure map by mistake, you cannot go back -- in ICS at least) let you work with only one route. And this would be a killer feature.

Comment: @macias Google has announced about offline navigation, but I don't know why they are late. I hope, we'll have that by the end of this October. It would really be killer feature.