# How can I make a route offline in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, offline, google-maps-navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get maps for off-line usage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27484/how-to-get-maps-for-off-line-usage)

Google maps recently added offline caching of maps. But I can only see a way to download a small area. If I'm going on a long road trip soon, is there any way I can tell it to download all the data for the navigational route between point A and point B?

I'm looking for it to be used for Google Navigation for driving between the two points with turn-by-turn directions.

Comment: Well, I know how to select a specific (small) region in GMaps and download it for offline. I'm specifically looking for how to do that for a whole ROUTE between two points, which out needing to manually download innumerable small sections along the route, specifically for use in Google Navigation.

Comment: Sure. My Nexus 7 (Jelly Bean) was able to sustain a certain time of being not connected (to a bluetooth tethered internet), I'm not really sure though if it is a viable solution for complete pre-loading and not just for temporary loss-of-cell-coverage situations only. For that you'd best bet on a real off-line solution like proposed in the answers in the linked question. At least there are no options (it's all auto-magically done), so I guess it's for bridging temporary no-cell-coverage situations only. Maybe the whole route is pre-downloaded but what will it do if you do a wrong turn?

Comment: I don't believe any flavours of Android support true route caching. You can save a route as a link though. This question might provide some ideas:
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27631/how-to-load-public-route-into-google-maps
As a backup, I use an Open Street Maps based utility for true offline use, such as OSMdroid.